# Array Formula in defined name only returns single value instead of array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is what I'm trying to achieve (in Excel 2016):

I have a sheet (named 'Relations') in Excel, containing a table (named 'Relations'), which contains a list of relevant contacts for my business, with name, addres, etc. The table also contains a column 'Code' to distinguish different contacts by a code.

On a separate sheet I would like to use a drop-down list with all contacts that have a code that starts with "DHR". My approach:

- Create a defined name (DHR_CONTACTS) that returns a list of the contact codes that start with "DHR".
- Create on the separate sheet a data validation (list) with a reference to the defined name.

Now I have a formula for the defined name (DHR_CONTACTS):

```
=INDEX(Relations[Code];SMALL(IF(LEFT(Relations[Code];3)="DHR";ROW(Relations[Code])-ROW(Relations[#Headers]));ROW(OFFSET(Relations!$A$1;0;0;COUNTIF(Relations[Code];"DHR*")))))
```

When I enter this formula using CSE in a range on my sheet it returns the expected results - a list of all codes that start with DHR, no matter how the table is sorted.

When I enter this formula in the defined name (DHR_CONTACTS) and create a data validation for a cell: =DHR_CONTACTS, my drop down list only shows the first code from the table that corresponds to the criteria.

Can anybody tell me if what I'm trying to do is even possible, and if so, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Note: I'm using the Dutch version of Excel, which uses a semi-colon as a separator between function arguments, however I translated the function names in English for the purpose of this question.

Comment: I typically do this a little bit more messy, because I find the defined names has some issues (maybe bugs) with array formulas.

So I typically create a dummy range somewhere in excel, and use your index formula to punch out all the data there, then just use an offset and a countif to create the defined name over the calculated values

Comment: There are no bugs that I know of with regard to array formulas and Defined Names. In order to obtain the results within the worksheet that the OP indicates, the given formula must be committed as a MULTI-CELL array formula. Formulas entered as Defined Names, however, are evaluated as SINGLE-CELL array formulas.

Comment: @XORLX: Your remark probably means that it is not possible to achieve my goal via a defined name directly. Do you have an alternatieve solution or should I go with Bryan's suggestion (which was my original solution) and create a temporary list on a separate dummy sheet?

Comment: Correct. Unfortunately a Data Validation list cannot be generated via a formula which generates a dynamic series of results, either directly or using a Defined Name.

Comment: @XORLX: I'm not sure whether this example fits your previous statement, but I do generate dynamic data validation lists via the function (defined name): =OFFSET(Table[[#Headers];[Col1]]; 1; 0; Table[[#Totals];[Col1]]) where Col1 is an example column in a table, and the Totals row shows the Count-Sum. Creating a data validation list with this defined name creates a dynamic drop down list with all entries from Col1.

Comment: Apologies. My definition was a poor one, since the example you give is also "dynamic". To clarify, the list passed must refer to either a range of contiguous cells within the worksheet, or else some construction which resolves as such (your OFFSET example being a case of the latter).